# How to handle regressions with some of the observations have multiple occurances and other do not

Tags: regression, repeated-measures

I have a dataset of users' actions online. Let's say that it represents the behavior of users on an online content site - some users visit the site multiple times, some only once. Every observation represents a visit to the site and include the actions taken by that user on that visit. I want to control for the user ID (maybe some users tend to share content while others do not). I tried to model a linear regression with the user id as fixed effects (using the lfe R package that handles factor variables with multiple levels) but as only a small amount of the users have indeed multiple observation, these anlyses fail to show real results. What is the best way to handle this configuration? I can run seperate regressions for repeated and non-repeated users, but I don't think that this is optimal...

Comment: Have you considered using mixed-effects models?

Comment: I'm now considering it... I don't have experience with random effect - I thought to have the user IDs as fixed effect but this may be wrong.. Is there any limitation in mixed models with the unequal number of repeated measures (some have multiple, some don't...)?

Comment: I believe that's OK. The book "Mixed-effects models in S and S-Plus" by Pinheiro and Bates is a good introduction, and you can probably find useful material online too.